# A good-enough Linux IDE for Groovy/Grails code completion?

Tags: linux, ide, grails, groovy

Is there a good development IDE for Groovy/Grails code completion under Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best one is IntelliJ IDEA (IMHO).
Then comes Eclipse and Netbeans.
But anyway, code completion isn't a strong point of those IDEs because of groovy's dynamic nature.

Comment: Despite the dynamic nature of Groovy code completions is quite good in IntelliJ. Ofcourse this also dependend on coding style etc, ...

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse with the Groovy Plugin?

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin

The SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) provides Grails integration:

http://grails.org/STS+Integration

Although I've read that the best IDE with support for Groovy/Grails is IntelliJ.  See:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy_grails.html

Comment: The Groovy and Grails support in eclipse is truely pathetic. Specifically code completion does not use any type inference, and is thus useless most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using *Netbeans 6.7 Beta* on Ubuntu for Grails development. This setup is very usable in general. The only problem I have is that code completion is very slow.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is it because of the dynamic nature of Grails?

Comment: I have the same problem on a really new / fast computer. Sometimes I'm able to Google the API and come up with the methods before Netbeans 6.7 Beta.

Comment: same Problem here at my Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

SpringSource Tool Suite

Answer (score 0):

check also [netbeans groovy/grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/NetBeans+Integration)

Answer (score 0):

I am a die-hard Eclipse user but have to say, try IDEA for Groovy/Grails support.  It is much better that the current Eclipse plugin.

Comment: current Eclipse Plugin is still buggy. At the moment i prefer Netbeans Integration.

Comment: I use Eclipse for C++, but use Netbeans for Groovy. Eclipse + Groovy doesn't work well for me. Lots of bugs/glitches